# Get first next Monday after certain date?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I know there is the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565356/get-first-monday-after-certain-date), but I have tried the answer provided and it returned an output that I don't understand. I am confused by the answer and I don't think the output is correct.

I need help, thank you  :)

```
GregorianCalendar date1 = new GregorianCalendar( 2014, 05, 12 ); //05 is june as month start from 0 -11

while( date1.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) != Calendar.MONDAY )
    date1.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );  

System.out.println(date1);
```

Here is the output:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1405267200000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Singapore",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=9,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=29,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=14,DAY_OF_YEAR=195,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Where on the output should I extract to retrieve Monday's date?

Comment: Do you want the Monday before or after the specified date?

Comment: after specified date :)

Comment: System.out.println(date1.getTime());

Comment: `DAY_OF_WEEK=2` - output looks correct (albeit not human-friendly).

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin the output is "Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 SGT 2014", well now i know the code is for 1st monday on the month, what i seek actually was the fist next monday date after given specific date like if given date is 12 june 2014 it will return Mon 16 june 2014..than you Rod for your quick reply

Comment: If you're able to use Java 8, I'd advise you to use the `java.time` classes. Otherwise, I'd advise you to use Joda Time. Note that currently you're trying to find the next Monday (or today - your while loop won't iterate even once if it's already Monday) *in the system time zone*. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet, yes jon that is exactly what i am currently looking for, i dont think changing to java 8 is an option at the current state. ill look at joda time :)

Comment: `Calendar` months are `0` indexed, you've specified July not June...

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, its a relieve i don't have to start researching joda time at this moment :). it work and i should have realize that earlier.

Comment: @beNice I'd still consider using JodaTime when you can

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve current week's Monday's date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307884/retrieve-current-weeks-mondays-date)

Comment: @Basil Bourque, please remove the duplicate statement, that question you refer was for current monday of the week, not next monday after date specified, that is one different question and different kind of answer. better kept this post for other who face same scenario as me, beside, this post was the extension of this 2011 post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565356/get-first-monday-after-certain-date

Comment: @beNice Really?! Passing today's date is different that passing a specific date? How is that different? Still seems like the exact same question to me. Or am I missing some other nuance?

Comment: I've added a [detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29724887/642706) using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library with discussion and example code, on the 2011 dup Question, [Get first Monday after certain date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7565356/642706).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## Java 8+

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.JUNE, 12);
System.out.println(ld);
ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
System.out.println(ld);
```

Which prints...

```
2014-06-12
2014-06-16
```

Because it's possible that the date my actually be a Monday, you could also use...

```
ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
```

## Java <= 7

You should be using the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), which gives you the support of the Java 8 Date/Time API

## Original Answer

Instead of `System.out.println(date1);` use `System.out.println(date1.getTime());`

`getTime` returns an instance of `Date` which represents the current state of the `Calendar`

Which will output `Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 EST 2014`

`System.out.println(date1)` is the equivlent of using `System.out.println(date1.toString())`, which, in this case, is dumping a bunch of useful info about the state of the `Calendar` object, but not really human readable data.

`System.out.println(date1.getTime())` will use the `Date`'s to `toString` method to display a date value, formatted based on the current local settings, which will provide more useful information.

**Updated**

Instead of using `GregorianCalendar`, you should use the system `Calendar`, for example...

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
date1.set(2014, 06, 12);
```

Also, months are `0` indexed, meaning that Janurary is actually `0` not `1`, so in your example, you've specified the month as July, not June.

So, instead, using...

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
date1.set(2014, 05, 12);

while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
    date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

System.out.println(date1.getTime());
```

Which outputted...

```
Mon Jun 16 16:22:26 EST 2014
```

Which is next Monday from today...more or less ;)

Comment: Custom `TemporalAdjuster` example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619409/java-8-find-nth-dayofweek-after-specific-day-of-month

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.JUNE , 12 )                    // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
         .with(                                           // Move from one date to another by passing an implementation of the `TemporalAdjuster` interface. 
             TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )   // Use an existing implementation found on utility class `TemporalAdjusters` (plural versus singular).
         )                                                // Returns another fresh `LocalDate` object rather than altering the original, per immutable objects design.
```

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.JUNE , 12 ) ;
```

To get the following Monday, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
LocalDate nextMonday = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

If you want to go with the original date if it is itself a Monday, then use `nextOrSame` adjuster.

```
LocalDate nextOrSameMonday = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

A minor change to your code:

```
    GregorianCalendar date1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 6, 12);

    while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
        date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date1.getTime()));
```

Yields:

```
 14-07-2014
```

EDIT: As per the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29) documentation, the constructor you are using, expects a 0 based month index, so for the month of June, you will need to pass in a value of 5, not 6.

Comment: Why `new Date(date1.getTimeInMillis()))` when `date1.getTime()` returns a `Date` object

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - Instead of looping, you could just use the switch statement along with the Calendar.add() like this:

```
int weekdayNum = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    switch (weekdayNum) {
    case 1: {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
        break;
    }
    case 5: {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
        break;
    }
    case 6: {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
        break;
    }
    case 7: {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Just do some simple math. Since `Calender.Monday` equals 2, it is easy to calculate the number of days that need to be added to the current date.

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
date1.set(2014, 05, 12);
int dayOfWeek = date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
date1.add(Calendar.DATE, (9 - dayOfWeek) % 7);
```

Comment: I do not see where you find the information that Monday equals 2. Can you explain?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @Yunnosch [`Calendar.MONDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONDAY) is indeed [documented as being a constant of type `int` with a value of `2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY). This numbering is peculiar to North America and other regions that commonly consider Sunday as first day of the week. The ISO 8601 standard defines Monday as first day. One of many reasons to avoid this troublesome old legacy class and instead use the modern java.time classes like `DayOfWeek` enum which follows the standard.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along totally different, and wrong, routes.