# Java 8: Find nth DayOfWeek after specific day of month

Tags: java, datetime, dayofweek, localdate

In Java 8, what I found is

```
TemporalAdjuster temporal = dayOfWeekInMonth(1,DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
```

gives the temporal for the first Monday of a month, and

```
next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
```

gives the next Monday after a specific date.

But I want to find nth MONDAY after specific date.

For example, I want 2nd MONDAY after 2017-06-06 and it should be 2017-06-19
where

`dayOfWeekInMonth(2,DayOfWeek.MONDAY)`

will give me 2017-06-12 and

```
next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
```

has of course no  parameter for the nth DayOfWeek's indicator. It will give the next first MONDAY which is 2017-06-12.

How I can calculate it without looping?

Comment: Related: [Get first next Monday after certain date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177516/get-first-next-monday-after-certain-date)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write an implementation of the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface.

Find the next monday, then add (N - 1) weeks:

```
public static TemporalAdjuster nextNthDayOfWeek(int n, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    return temporal -> {
        Temporal next = temporal.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(dayOfWeek));
        return next.plus(n - 1, ChronoUnit.WEEKS);
    };
}
```

Pass your `TemporalAdjuster` object to [`LocalDate.with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-). Get back another `LocalDate` with your desired result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 7);
    date = date.with(nextNthDayOfWeek(2, DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    System.out.println("date = " + date); // prints 2017-03-20
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice solution!