# Determine next Day's Date in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, days

How to determine the next day's date by passing a certain day of the week?

For example, if today (03 June) I pass ****Monday****, it will give me **07 JUNE** because the next Monday will be 07 June?

We are on: **Sunday 06 June**, If I enter:

- **Sunday** , return **06 June**
- **Monday** , return **07 June**
- **Tuesday**, return **08 June**

Comment: Use the `java.time` API and then `plus` one day. For example `ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(1)`.

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24177555/1039920

Comment: @MarkSholund Spot on! (if I understood the question correctly)

Comment: See [`TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next(java.time.DayOfWeek)). If you were to carefully edit your Question to be clear and specific, perhaps it could be reopened and a full Answer written.

Comment: If today was already a Monday, would you want today’s date or the following Monday?

Comment: As mentionned in the example; we are on Wednesday, If I enter the word Thursday, it will give me the next Thursday's Date.

Comment: @OleV.V. It will give today's date

Answer (score 4):

## *java.time*

Use [`LocalDate#with(TemporalAdjuster)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) to get the required `LocalDate`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameDate(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY).format(dtf));
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameDate(DayOfWeek.MONDAY).format(dtf));
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameDate(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY).format(dtf));
    }

    static LocalDate getNextOrSameDate(DayOfWeek dw) {
        return LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dw));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
06 June
07 June
08 June
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/CKBB81)

**Alternatively,** you can return the weekday name directly from the function.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameWeekDayName(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameWeekDayName(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameWeekDayName(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY));
    }

    static String getNextOrSameWeekDayName(DayOfWeek dw) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dw)).format(dtf);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/UCONrU)

**Alternatively,** you can pass the weekday name as `String` and return any of the things as shown above. However, this is error-prone and I recommend you pass an `enum` instead of a `String` as shown in previous examples.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameWeekDayName("Sunday"));
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameWeekDayName("Monday"));
        System.out.println(getNextOrSameWeekDayName("Tuesday"));
    }

    static String getNextOrSameWeekDayName(String dw) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return LocalDate.now()
                .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.valueOf(dw.toUpperCase())))
                .format(dtf);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/7qsiY8)

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>